# How to print all users from domain (over 500) Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I found the following article :

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/apps-script

which instructs you to get all users from your google domain. I'd like to get ALL of the users however, but maxResults  seems to limit the results to a maximum of 500 result entries. How can I bypass this and get all users? I'm using the following code.

```
  function listUsers() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 5000,
    orderBy: 'email'
    
  };
  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
  var users = response.users;
  if (users && users.length > 0) {
    Logger.log(users.length);
    Logger.log('Users:');
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see a limit of 500? I don't see a limit specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list), but I do see that the results are paginated. Are you retrieving all of the paginated results?

Comment: I've updated with my code but I'm still getting the limit of 500. Even though I'm not paginating the results.

Comment: You haven't updated the [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the paginated results by including the `nextPageToken` from the response in the parameters of subsequent calls as `pageToken`.

```
function getAllUsers() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    domain: 'example.com',
    orderBy: 'email'
  };
  var response = {};
  var users = [];

  do {
    optionalArgs.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
    users = users.concat(response.users);
  } while (response.nextPageToken);
  
  return users;
}
```

Comment: How do I print the users into the log with this code?

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic `console.log(getAllUsers())`

Comment: Where does that line go? I get the error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (rad: 2, fil: Kod2)"

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic I suggest that you review basic javascript if you want to pursue an apps script project. The function I posted returns an array of users. You should create another function to apply whatever actions you want on those users. `function test() { console.log(getAllUsers()); }`.

Comment: That error may be due to number of users you have or the V8 runtime. If it persists, try [disabling the V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_rhino_runtime). I've updated the code to remove V8-specific syntax.